# Boot menu does not offer choice between Ubuntu and Windows

Tags: boot, swap

I installed Ubuntu 11.10 on my desktop in Local Drive D as Local drive C was already having Windows Xp. I chose *something else* while installing Ubuntu and formatted with ext3 and chose use as *'/'*. But i didn't chose any partition for *swap*. Now when i rebooted the system after unplugging my USB, I found no boot menu offering choice between Windows and Ubuntu.Simply windows starts up. Moreover now i can't see any Local Drive D on Windows.However, using my bootable pendrive I were able to use Ubuntu directly from USB  and can find Local Drive D & C (both with new name *"21 System File"*) there with Ubuntu files loaded there.

So now how can I switch between Ubuntu and Windows and find Local Drive D on my Windows.

Comment: Did you take a look at [this tool](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

Answer (score 1):

Run windows. Run:

```
msconfig
```

and search for option describing how long should it show other systems. At my XP it is in BOOT.INI and is called

```
time limit.
```

Set it to 30s.

If that doesn't help then I suggest to edit grub.conf file. But first try this and let us know if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

After selecting "Something else" confirm that your internal drive, (sda), is selected for bootloader installation, not the USB drive.

If you can boot the Ubuntu install on drive D, using the USB drive, go to terminal and do a `sudo update-grub`.

Windows does not see ext3 partitions.